# Web Api Error: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a Web Api conroller that allows my users to log-in to the site using their credentials (username, password).

**Scenario:**

After typing the username and password, click login. I need to get this info(username and password) and see if it exists in the users table in my db. this part is taken care of. When I hard code the username and password to my code it works fine. I get true if the credentials correct and false when incorrect. Now, how can I get this values from the user - the URL or perhaps another way that I am not aware of?

Currently, I get the following error:

```
 {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
 'http://localhost:4453/api/login/username/password'.","MessageDetail":"No
 action was found on the controller 'Login' that matches the request."}
```

Please keep in mind that this is my second day looking at Web Api.

Here is my code I am not sure what went wrong.

**Controller:**

```
    public bool Get(string txtLoginId, string txtPassword)
    {
        Authenticate(txtLoginId, txtPassword);
        return loggedin;
    }
```

**WebApiConfig**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Authentication(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "AuthenticationApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{user}/{pass}",
            defaults: new { user = RouteParameter.Optional, pass = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your route parameter names have to match your action parameter names.
Change your Action to:

```
public bool Get(string user, string pass)
{
    Authenticate(user, pass);
    return loggedin;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. Now, to post it I need to use a function with the name post? I want to post the Boolean value.

Comment: I suggest you go through the examples at the [Asp.NET Web API site](http://www.asp.net/web-api). They should answer most of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the route parameter name and method parameter name matches

Comment: Dear @Simon, Please explain more with examples.

Comment: @desmati,Use attribute based routing in this case then: [Route("api/yourcontroller/{name})] in your method: public IHttpActionResult GetByName(name) note how the "name" parameter in the [Route] attribute match with that of the GetByName()method